# Java: Using typed keystrokes with modifiers

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to implement keyboard shortcuts for my application that are independent of the keyboard layout, for example using Ctrl-+ for zooming.

I assumed the correct way of doing so is something like:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(new Character('+'), 0)
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(new Character('+'), InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK)
```

Unfortunately, only the first way seems to be working, while I would like to make use of a modifier key such as in the second line.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is a complete snippet:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class KeystrokeTest extends JFrame{
    JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
    public KeystrokeTest(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label.setVisible(!label.isVisible());
            }
        }, 
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(new Character('+'), InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),
        JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        add(panel);
        setSize(200,200);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeystrokeTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line instead

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
```

Comment: thanks @ codeMan, that works but is not what I want: KeyEvent.VK_PLUS refers to the key plus, not to the typed character. That means, it only works on keyboard layouts where '+' is on the primary layer (like the German keyboard), but not say on the US layout where '+' is accessed via 'Shift ='. By providing Character('+') as an argument, I specify that I am interested in the typed '+', but unfortunately it does not seem to work with modifier keys (despite the documentation which says otherwise).